# Dart2JS and Enumerators

Tags: enums, dart, dart2js

I'm using enumerators (experimental) in my project. Pub Build (Generate JS) in my Dart Editor does not work due to the enums. In my console, this command:

```
dart2js file.dart --enable-enum
```

does work, but it is inconvinient to do it through the console. Is there any way to add arguments to the default command in Dart Editor (--enable-enums) so it'd allow it to compile into JS?

Running it by default in Dartium works and when copying and pasting the server url (`http://localhost:8080/index.html`), the dart2js is triggered and it starts working (after average compilation time).

EDIT: Yes, I have enums enabled in my editor.

EDIT2: To enable enums in dart2js, I have this transformer in pubspec.yaml:

```
transformers:
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-enum]
```

However, I get this error in a file, which uses enums:

```
Directive not allowed here.
part of thing;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Info from Dart2JS]:
```

It's weird that it works in the console with the same arguments and not in the editor.

I have filled a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21985&thanks=24524&ts=1420201499).

Comment: Is your enum defined in a `part` file? Is `dart2js` the last transformer in your `pubspec.yaml` transformer section?

Comment: Yes. The enum is defined in a part, but dart2js transformer is the only one, is it's the last one.

Comment: Why are you using `--enable-enums` (plural) on command line and `--enable-enum` (singular) in the pubspec.yaml transformer config. I think it should be the same (singular on both) https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21823#c3

Comment: The command line argument has a typo. Sorry. Singular should be correct AFAIK.

Comment: Have you tried to declare the enum in a library instead of a part? If this works I guess it is a bug with `part`.

Comment: Please post the link here if you file a bug report at dartbug.com.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21985&thanks=24524&ts=1420201499

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2016, the enumerators are fully implemented.